# How to turn multiple parameters into a single parameter in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, parameters, uri, protocols

**This topic is really hard to explain, so try to understand it.** I'm working on a project called RoSOX that uses a URI to join a server (on another end)
However, this batch program requires at least 3 parameters. If you were to run it under the Windows Command Prompt, you would run it like this ***RoSOXLauncher.bat "IPHere" "PortHere" "UsernameHere"***. This is the code that obtains those values (Not the entire program though)

```
@echo off
set ip=%~1
set port=%~2
set username=%~3
```

Unfortunately, I found another post mentioning that URI Protocols (aka Registry Entries that allow starting a program from your web browser, such as "**mailto:example@example.com**") only accept 1 parameter regardless of the program. My theory to bypass this is to have the input connected by commas so it's considered one parameter. It would be written like this: ***RoSOXLauncher.bat*** **IPHere**,**PortHere**,**UsernameHere** An example would be [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5geA.png) The logarithm would be

- Disassemble the values from the commas (The FOR command is probably used)
- Take each value and put it into its own variable
- Continue the rest of the script

Does anyone know how this logarithm would be wrote in Batch? This  is the only thing preventing me from having my program run correctly.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You've told us that you have three parameters and that you can only pass one, but you haven't stated what that single parameter is, _(which is accepted by your URI)_. I'm not sure if you've taken the [tour] or read [ask], but we're here to help you fix your code and you've not provided any. Currently your question is off topic, you need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50440521/edit) it to rectify that.

Comment: @Compo Sorry about that, I was kinda desperate as to how to find the answer to my question I forgot to explain it better, yes I've read both pages. I'll edit it immediately.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, if you pass three parameters to your `.bat` file, why can you not create a single parameter in the batch file using them? Have you tried it? What happened? If you cannot tell us what is wrong, or in fact if anything is wrong, helping you to fix it seems a little optimistic. BTW, the comma is also a parameter delimiter!

Comment: @Compo I cannot create a single parameter in my batch file normally, for the IP and Port and Username have to be separate variables. I know it's hard to explain it but when the launcher goes to start the client it needs those three variables to join the correct server. Here, I figure with this flash slideshow it'll seem more clear: http://www.filedropper.com/ireallyneedhelp

Comment: xxxman360, I'm afraid, I don't have any sort of flash player, nor would I feel comfortable downloading such a thing. Could you not upload it to your question as an animated gif via the image link? Where are the input parameters coming from for the batch file? and in what format? and have you got any control over that format? What does your batch file do with the variables? I'm assuming it just passes them as part of a series of strings to another program, _possibly a web browser_, what is that string? Could you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50440521/edit) to include it?

Comment: @Compo Don't worry anymore, Gerhard Barnard helped me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems very unclear as to what you want, but if I understand your requirement correctly then:

```
@echo off
set ip=%~1
set port=%~2
set username=%~3
```

Will still work if you do:

```
RoSOXLauncher.bat IPHere,PortHere,UsernameHere
```

Simply because the delimiters excepted are `whitespace`, comma and semicolon. You can try this and see for yourself.

```
RoSOXLauncher.bat IPHere;PortHere;UsernameHere
RoSOXLauncher.bat IPHere PortHere UsernameHere
```

Will do the same.

On the other hand, your program which you send the parameters from might also delimit by whitespace, command or semicolon, then you might simply use aother common delimiter like `-` or `:` see this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%i in ("%~1") do (
  echo ip %%i
  echo port %%j
  echo username %%k
)
```

Which you can run using:

```
RoSOXLauncher.bat IPHere-PortHere-UsernameHere
```

or

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%i in ("%~1") do (
  echo ip %%i
  echo port %%j
  echo username %%k
)
```

which you can run with:

```
RoSOXLauncher.bat IPHere:PortHere:UsernameHere
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I knew it had something to do with the FOR command, I just didn't know how it would work. I appreciate your convince towards the help of my project.

Comment: No problem. But still keep in mind that `for` is not needed if you use `,` `;` or whitespace as per examples in the answer..